1. だれ "が" つくった。 2. だれ "の" つくった。whats the difference?
Whats the diffarance bitween
これ は だれ "が" つくった ケキ です か。 and
これ は だれ "の" つくった ケキ です か。

Both の and が were historically used as possessive markers. が specified for marking who an action figuratively "belonged to", transforming it into a marker for the grammatical subject -- the person or thing who does the action.
Because of its similar possessive use to が, の can also mark the subject, but only when the full clause it's in is describing another noun -- a kind of 'subordinate clause'.
So 誰が作ったケーキ（だれが つくった ケーキ） means "The cake that someone made".
誰の作ったケーキ（だれの つくった） means the same thing, but clarifies that 誰が作った is a subordinate clause of ケーキ. Both are acceptable.
In the context of the full sentence, 「これは誰が作ったケーキ」 and 「これは誰が作ったケーキ」 both mean "Who made this cake?".

This is not correct. の replacing が in relative clauses is a well-established phenomenon (such as 「背の高い人」)

Thank you, that was a pretty big flub on my part. I've corrected it.
